# Get duplicate characters in string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, character, repeat

I try to match/get all repetitions in a string. This is what I've done so far:

```
var str = 'abcabc123123';
var REPEATED_CHARS_REGEX = /(.).*\1/gi;

console.log( str.match(REPEATED_CHARS_REGEX) ); // => ['abca', '1231']
```

As you can see the matching result is `['abca', '1231']`, but I excpect to get `['abc', '123']`. Any ideas to accomplish that?

**2nd question:**

Another thing I excpect, is to make it possible to change the *duration* how often a char needs to be in the string to get matched...

For example if the string is `abcabcabc` and the *repetation-time* is set to `2` it should result in `['abcabc']`. If set to `3` it should be `['abc']`.

**Update**

A non-`RegExp` solution is perfectly alright!

Comment: What do you expect with the string: `abc123ab12`?

Comment: @M42 Mhh, `['ab', '12']`...

Comment: The reason you're getting `'abca'` and `'1231'` is that your regex matches any one character `(.)` followed by any number of other characters `.*` followed by whatever the first character was `\1`. You need to change the part in the parentheses to match all of the first group of letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I think [falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru) had a good idea with a zero-width look-ahead.

```
'abcabc123123'.match(/(.+)(?=\1)/g)
// ["abc", "123"]
```

This allows it to match just the initial substring while ensuring at least 1 repetition follows.

For [M42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/m42)'s follow-up example, it could be modified with a `.*?` to allow for gaps between repetitions.

```
'abc123ab12'.match(/(.+)(?=.*?\1)/g)
// ["ab", "12"]
```

Then, to find where the repetition starts with multiple uses together, a quantifier (`{n}`) can be added for the capture group:

```
'abcabc1234abc'.match(/(.+){2}(?=.*?\1)/g)
// ["abcabc"]
```

Or, to match just the initial with a number of repetitions following, add the quantifier within the look-ahead.

```
'abc123ab12ab'.match(/(.+)(?=(.*?\1){2})/g)
// ["ab"]
```

It can also match a minimum number of repetitions with a range quantifier without a max -- `{2,}`

```
'abcd1234ab12cd34bcd234'.match(/(.+)(?=(.*?\1){2,})/g)
// ["b", "cd", "2", "34"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution may be used if you don't want to use regex:

```
function test() {
    var stringToTest = 'find the first duplicate character in the string';
    var a = stringToTest.split('');
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        var letterToCompare = a[i];
        for (var j=i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
            if (letterToCompare == a[j]) {
                console.log('first Duplicate found');
                console.log(letterToCompare);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above returns more *duplicates* than there actually are. The second for loop causes the problem and is unnecessary. Try this:

```
function stringParse(string){
  var arr = string.split("");
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var letterToCompare = arr[i];
    var j= i+1;
    if(letterToCompare === arr[j]){
      console.log('duplicate found');
      console.log(letterToCompare);
    }    
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var duplicateCheck = function(stru) {
>     var flag = false;
>     for (let o = 0; o < stru.length; o++) {
>         for (let p = 0; p < stru.length; p++) {
>             if (stru.charAt(o) === stru.charAt(p) && o!==p) {
>                 flag = true;
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     
>     return flag;
> }
> ```

true ==> duplicate found