# JavaScript Split string by multiple occurrences of letters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string by a single or multiple occurrence of letters.

**For example:**

`aaabbcapppp`, would yield the array, `["aaa", "bb", "c", "a", "pppp"]`

The most-Inefficient idea I had was to just utilize, `newArray = str.split("");` and rebuild the array to my needs.  I assume there is a much more efficient solution.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170955/get-duplicate-characters-in-string

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
"aaabbcapppp".match(/(.)\1*/g) // ["aaa", "bb", "c", "a", "pppp"]
```

The `(.)` matches any single character, captured in group 1, followed by that same character repeated zero or more times (`\1` is a backreference which matches exactly what was matched in group 1).

To match only Latin letters, consider using `[a-z]`, for example:

```
"aaa-bbca!!pppp".match(/([a-z])\1*/g) // ["aaa", "bb", "c", "a", "pppp"]
```

Here, the `-` and `!!` are not included in the result array.

Answer (score 1):

The regex solution is probably the way to go, but if for some reason you want to do it manually, something like this would work

```
function charSplit(str) {
    var arr = [], l, j = -1;
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        var c = str.charAt(i);
        l==c ? arr[j] += c : arr[++j] = c;
        l=c;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MJQM8/)

Comment: +1 Seems like this might possibly be improved by finding the index of the first and last character in a run then doing a substring rather than concatenation. I like it though.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - Thanks, +1 to you to. And yes, it could probably be improved, but this was as simple as I could get it, I even minified it for fun -> http://jsfiddle.net/MJQM8/1/