# Split string by occurrences character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to use in the `split()` function in order to split a string, following these rules:

1. If a `\` is found, than a split is made before the `\` and after the char after the one after the `\` (e.g. `"Hel\\7o".split()` → `["Hel", "\7", "o"]`;
2. If a `%` is found, we have similar behavior, but I accept only letters. (e.g. `"He%7l%lo".split()` → `["He%7l", "%l", "o"]`;
3. If there's something string in between `""` or `''`, they are split (e.g. `"Hel\"lo\"".split()` → `["Hel", ""lo""]`;
4. If a , or `:`, or `/`, is found, we split (e.g. `"Hel/lo Wor:ld".split()` → `["Hel", "/", "lo", " ", "Wor", ":", "ld"]`;

I've accomplished what's I've said so far with this following regex: `/(\\.|%[a-zA-Z]|\".*\"|\'.*\'|:|\/| )/`.

Now, I need one last split rule, which is that I need to split the occurrences of a char from the occurrences of other char. Basically, if I have `"mmDD"`, I would like to have `["mm", "DD"]`.
Of course, this would need to work with all the other rules so far, so `"mm mmDDYYy%y"` would return `["mm", " ", "mm", "DD", "YY", "y", "%y"]`.
In this last example you can also see that this last rule needs to be case-sensitive (`"YY"` is split from `"y"`).

I've found this answer -> [JavaScript Split string by multiple occurrences of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997437/javascript-split-string-by-multiple-occurrences-of-letters) But it doesn't help me since it loses the number of occurrences (e.g. `"mmDD".split(/(.)\1*/)` returns `["m","D"]`, but I needed `["mm","DD"]`.

I've tried to play with basically all the regex rules, but I'm losing my mind after this. Is it even possible directly with the `split()` function?

Thanks for help.

**EDIT:** If it helps, here's the regex101 link https://regex101.com/r/ezXKkG/1/

Also, Wiktor Stribiżew suggested `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z]))`, which I added in the global rule, as follow: `/(\\.|%[a-zA-Z]|\".*\"|\'.*\'|:|\/| |(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z]))/`.

With this, `"MMmm"` is split in `["MM", "mm"]` (NICE!), but it doesn't work in case like: `"MMmdD"`, which is split in `["MM", "md", "D"]`

Comment: There is no literal ``\`` in ``"Hel\7o"``, did you mean to write ``"Hel\\7o"``? Or do you want to search for control characters?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I noticed some errors in the question, there's just too many chars without space :S I'm correcting it. EDIT: now it should be all ok

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is possible via regex in JavaScript. It should be doable using lookbehinds but those aren't standard. And even *with* the lookbehinds, the regex would be rather ugly, as you need multiple conditions for each rules and branch off for the rules, as well. So you'd have at least 8 branches (4 rules * 2 conditions each) and this can quickly get hard to read and maintain.

Comment: Can you put an example in https://regex101.com/ and partage to us plz, it easy for us to see what you need exactly

Comment: @YiaoSun regex101 is of little help here, as this is supposed to be a *split* and it should be done by zero width characters. I don't think those would be shown.

Comment: You want to use capturing groups with split to tokenize the string, but with `(.)\2+` you would need to make `split` ignore the capturing group output. It won't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually, what you wrote before ( I had the time to try before you deleted it :P ) almost nailed it: I'm gonna edit the question to show you the result
YiaoSun uhm, here's the link https://regex101.com/r/ezXKkG/1 but VLAZ is right, I'm using split, not match, so..

Comment: Almost does not make the solution.

Comment: I was just thanking you for the effort, and giving the others an hint. I honestly don't know if it's "not possible", that's why I added your partial solution

Comment: Why would `DDYY` split to `DD,YY` using any of your rules mentioned.?

Comment: The best idea is to revamp the pattern to match instead of split.

Comment: Probably has a few issues but give it a try `str.split(/(\\.|%[a-zA-Z]|\".*\"|\'.*\'|:|\/| |(.)\2+)/).filter(Boolean).filter((w,i,a) => !(a[i-1] !== void 0 && a[i-1].length > w.length && a[i-1][0] === w[0]));`

Comment: Keith, that is the missing rule >.< After the fourth rule I explain I'm searching for a last one rule.
Wiktor, the fact is that I do need to have the different pieces separated, I don't care knowing about matching.
@revo Uhm, from the test I've made so far, it seems it works.. But, can you explain me your answer? I don't get the last filter function

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the only way I managed to resolve the problem was to divide my goal in two:

1. Using a regex similar to the one I first mentioned ( `/(\\.|%[a-zA-Z]|\"[^"]*\"|\'[^']*\'|:|\/| +|\w+)/` ), I split the string following the first four rules I required;
2. To achieve the fifth and last rule, I run the following piece of code:

   ```
   tokens = toSplit.split(/(\\.|%[a-zA-Z]|\".*\"|\'.*\'|:|\/| )/);
   tokens.forEach(token => {
       if (/^[a-zA-Z]$/).test(token) {
           let newToken = '';

           for (let i = 0, len = token.length; i < len; i++) {
               const tokenChar = token[i];
               const lastChar = newToken[newToken.length - 1];
               if (lastChar && lastChar !== tokenChar) {
                   // saving newToken
                   newToken= '';
               }

               newToken+= tokenChar;
           }
       }
   )}
   ```

Basically, for each string I've retrieved with the regex, I check if it's formed by only chars. If so, I manually split the string in different substring iterating on it.

I know this answer does not resolve the problem using only regex in `split` function, but I haven't found any other solution so far. At least this one works, and someone else may found it useful.