# List repeating letters JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

is there a way to list string's repeating letters? I want to use regex in my function but for now it only tells me is there are duplicates or not. Can I push them into array somehow?

```
function repeating(str) {
    //this part returns true/false
    var hasDuplicates = (/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/).test(str);
    return hasDuplicates;

   //I tried with something like this but it returns whole word, not letters
   var duplicates = str.match(/(.).*\1/gi);
   return duplicates;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170955/get-duplicate-characters-in-string

Comment: You almost got it: `"abcab".match(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g)`